# Belief Propagation in Computer Vision

Tags: artificial-intelligence, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on dense matching using DSP algorithm.
They have used belief propagation to optimize their energy function?
How do we do it?
I mean how do we assign prior belief?
Link: [Deformable Spatial Pyramid Matching for Fast Dense Correspondences](http://vision.cs.utexas.edu/projects/dsp/)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Please edit the question to clarify.  What do you mean by "using DSP algorithm"?  What do you mean by "They have used" -- who has used?  "How do we do it" -- do what?   "prior belief" for what?   This needs more context to be answerable.  Please put effort into your questions to make them understandable -- they shouldn't be just a stream of consciousness.

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!